# Why are non-logical predicates of 0-arity treated as logical variables?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, quine

In the "[Non-logical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Non-logical_symbols)" section of Wikipedia, it states:

> A predicate symbol (or relation symbol) with some valence (or arity,
>   number of arguments) greater than or equal to 0. These are often
>   denoted by uppercase letters P, Q, R,...

I believe I understand why predicate symbols, in general, are "non-logical", but correct me if I'm wrong:

A predicate symbol with arity N is also known as a relation symbol and as such, it denotes a non-logical mathematical object -- a class of relationships each between N objects.  This class is devoid of any "logical" interpretation, i.e. any notion of truth, prior to a model theoretic interpretation.

That being the case, it would seem that the most parsimonious denotation of a predicate with arity N=0 would *also* be a non-logical object -- that is it would denote a constant of the language, rather than denoting logical meaning, i.e. truth (again, as it is prior to a model).

However, continuing the quotation:

> Relations of valence 0 can be identified with propositional variables.
>   For example, P, which can stand for any statement.

While I understand that function symbols of 0-arity serve as constant symbols in FOL, function symbols seem superfluous, a mere convenience, since their purpose is to denote structured objects and structure obtains through relationships between objects and such relationships are denoted by predicates.

Moreover, Quine goes so far as to render superfluous even the necessity of named constants by appropriately quantifying 1-arity predicates standing in for such names, such as the object denoted by 'a' with the 1-arity predicate 'A':

> (∃x)A(x) & ~ (∃x,y)(A(x) & A(y) & ~(x=y) )
>
> ...(This identity sign “=” here would either count as one of the
>   simple predicates of the language or be paraphrased in terms of them.)][2](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674665637)

Indeed, Quine goes on to make the point:

> The functors, again, are just convenient redundancy; they can all be
>   dropped in favor of appropriate predicates, by an extension of the
>   method by which we dropped names.

Comment: I do not follow. A predicate/relation symbol is a function with T/F as values, a 0-arity one is a function with no arguments, i.e. a constant. If you also vary interpretation it becomes a variable (over them).

Comment: Yes, in principle function symbols are dispensable. Only predicate symbols are needed. But the practice of using function symbol is very very useful, because it match the usual practice of mathematics : **+, x**, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a predicate of 0-arity considered as a sentence letter?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/60148/why-is-a-predicate-of-0-arity-considered-as-a-sentence-letter)

Comment: Aside: while historic focus was on the notions of predicate and relation, there's a really significant modern trend to be interested in calculation, computation, transformations, and similar; where functions and types (or similar) play the central role. And since you get traditional logical notions "for free", the parsimonious thing to do is to take *function* as the primitive notion rather than *relation*.

Comment: Hurkyl, one would presume, then, that the notion that functions are degenerate relations has a dual that somehow asserts "relations are degenerate functions". Moreover, one would presume that comparison of the two in terms of parsimony would be concisely and emphatically pointed out in virtually all "modern" texts.  Cite?

Answer (score 2):

A 0-place predicate does not denote *logical* truth in the sense of a priori to a model-theoretic interpretation.
For a 2-place predicate like P(x,y), we need an interpretation of the individuals x and y to determine the truth of P(x,y) in the given model. For a 1-place predicate P(x), we need an interpretation of the individual x to determine the truth of P(x) in the model. For a 0-place predicate P(), we don't need to consider interpretation of individuals to determine the truth of P() in the model. **But still, we determine the truth of P() relative to a given model**. A zero-place predicate P will be evaluated by the model's interpretation function just like predicates of arity n >= 1 are. The interpretation of such a 0-place predicate will, unlike that of properties (n=1) or relations (n>1), not be a subset of the Cartesian product over individuals in the model, but still, it will be non-logical in the sense that its interpretation depends on the model's interpretation function, other than e.g. the interpretation of the logical symbols ⊤ or ⊥ which is constant across interpretations.

Consider the interpretation of P() to be the statement "It is raining" or "It is three o'clock": Clearly, while this statement is either true or false without depending on the denotation of some individual names, it is clearly a situation (~ =model) dependent truth and not an a prio logically true statement - in contrast to logical truths like p -> p or &bot which are true independent of a specific model-theoretic interpretation. A 0-place predicate is not a *logical* variable just because it is *propositional*. The fact that we have to interpret it against a model makes it a non-logical symbol.

Comment: Why would the sentence "It is raining." not be predicated as the arity-1 predicate `raining(it)`, with the arity-0 predicate`it` denoting the proposition `∃it` which, under the appropriate interpretation, is rendered true if `it` does indeed exist? As Quine seems to point out, the existential quantifier does have a rather singular role to play in reification of names.

Comment: Because the "it" in "It is raining" does not really refer to any individual, but is merely inserted as a dummy-subject because in English it happens to be ungrammatical to have sentences consisting of only a verb. In Spanish, the same would be expressed as "Llueve ("Rains"). Rain(x) would be possible, but would rather mean "This is rain". In "It is raining", however, there is no semantic subject, similarly to "It is three o'clock": it's not like there exists someone who is raining; the "it" does not have any denotation in the model, so we would treat the predicate "Rain" as subject-less.

Answer (score 1):

0-place predicates are not logical *symbols*, their meaning is specified by an interpretation. For any such 0-place predicate, in some interpretations it will come out true, and in other interpretations it will come out false. You called them logical *variables*, so I'm not sure if this is what you meant.

By the way, since you mentioned the equivalence between 0-place function symbols and constants, there's a really neat trick (in my opinion) that you may be interested in. It may help with your question too, since it removes some of the "ad hoc-ness" to viewing 0-place predicates as propositional variables/sentence letters.

In the same way that constants are unnecessary, and 0-place function symbols will do the job just fine, propositional variables are entirely unnecessary and 0-place predicates will do. Using a very neat little trick, you don't even need the clause that makes 0-place predicates seem like a "special" case by interpreting them as TRUE and FALSE, while predicates of arity n greater than 0 are interpreted as sets of n-tuples. You can interpret 0-place predicates in the same way (as sets of 0-tuples). Here's how:

As you know, we interpret n-place predicates as subsets of the [n-ary Cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_power) of the domain of discourse. Therefore, 0-place predicates are subsets of the 0-ary Cartesian power of the domain. For any set, [its 0-ary product is the set containing the null set, {Ø}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921712/what-is-a-set-raised-to-the-0-power-in-relation-to-the-definition-of-a-nullary). There are exactly two subsets of this 0-ary power, Ø and {Ø}. So, for any 0-place predicate we have exactly two possible interpretations, the two possible subsets of the domain to the power of zero. How convenient... So when we specify an interpretation for 0-place predicates, we can either interpret it as Ø or {Ø}, [and the empty set just is the empty 0-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Definitions) so Ø = <> and {Ø} = {<>}.

We pick the one {<>} one as meaning true, and {} as meaning false. And we interpret a 0-place predicate as {<>} when we want to say it's true in an interpretation, and {} when we want to say it's false in that interpretation.

Here's a quote that may explain it better, from *[Intermediate Logic](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/intermediate-logic-9780198751427?cc=us&lang=en&)* by David Bostock, reprinted 2002, the footnotes 11 and 12 on page 83 (he uses **Ф** to represent predicates, and vertical bars, |...| to represent interpretation):

> <sup>11</sup> We *could* avoid a special clause for for zero-place
>   predicates in this way. We may suppose that **D<sup>0</sup>** is the
>   set of 0-tuples that can be formed from the members of **D**, and that
>   there is just one such 0-tuple, namely 'the empty tuple' (i.e. the
>   empty sequence) which is represented by < >. Then **D<sup>0</sup>** =
>   {< >}, and if **|Ф|** ⊆ **D<sup>0</sup>** then either |**Ф**| = {< >}
>   or **|Ф|** = { } (i.e. the empty set). For a continuation of this
>   approach, see n. 12.
>
> <sup>12</sup> If this clause is intended to include 0-place
>   predicate-letters (cf. n. 11), then in their case it is interpreted as
>   meaning
>
> **|Ф|<sup>0</sup>** = T   if and only if   < > ∈ **|Ф|<sup>0</sup>**
>
> Thus a sentence-letter is true if its value is {< >}, and false if its
>   value is { }. (I am indebted to Dana Scott for this ingenious
>   suggestion.)

Comment: "You called them logical variables..." Actually, Wikipedia called them "propositional variables" and I took the liberty of saying "logical variables" based on the idea that "Unlike first-order logic, propositional logic does not deal with non-logical objects..." (quoting another Wikipedia article -- this one on "propositional calculus).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus

Comment: "...predicates of arity greater than 0 are *interpreted* as *sets* of n-tuples..."  I chose the word "class" rather than "set" so as to avoid any interpretation.  To quote a paper on Quinian interpretation "So the Tarskian, model-theoretic concepts of logical truth and consequence are intimately bound up with set theory, a fact that Quine finds spurious. According to Quine, in defining such a basic concept as logical truth, we should try to
get along without sets as far as possible."  https://homepage.univie.ac.at/guenther.eder/Boolos%20vs%20Quine.pdf

Comment: @JamesBowery (Just to make sure we're on the same page, logical variables = propositional variables = sentence symbols, right?) In first-order logic, when interpreting closed formulas, *logical symbols* (connectives, quantifiers, variables, and optionally identity and punctuation) are symbols whose meaning remain the same across all interpretations. *Non-logical symbols* (predicates, functions) are symbols that require an interpretation to determine the meaning. Truth values are neither logical or non-logical in the sense describes above, since they are not *symbols* of the language.

Comment: @JamesBowery Propositional variables are non-logical as much as predicates, since they need to be "manually" specified (by an interpretation) whether they are true or false; their meaning isn't fixed as true or false by the logic. Truth and falsehood are just part of the machinery we use to do the specifying, just like with relations/tuples/functions, etc. They are what the non-logical symbols name. It's like in propositional logic, where there are no predicates. Propositional variables are non-logical because the actual truth value they denote changes from interpretation to interpretation.

Comment: @JamesBowery I hope I'm understanding your question correctly, so please do let me know if I'm not!

Comment: "Truth values are neither logical or non-logical in the sense describes above, since they are not symbols of the language." seems contradicted by "12.2 First-Order Languages" "1. Logical symbols" "b) The propositional constant for falsity ⊥." 

http://builds.openlogicproject.org/open-logic-complete.pdf

Comment: @JamesBowery It's not. ⊥ is a logical *symbol* because it is always interpreted as the same truth value, but it is not a truth value itself. It is not what we use in specifying the values of an interpretation. We might, in a given interpretation, specify that the 0-place predicate P has a value of FALSE, but that's not the same as saying it's value is the symbol ⊥. Likewise, the symbol ⊥ is a logical symbol (it's a 0-place connective) because it is always interpreted in the same way, as the value FALSE. But the symbol ⊥ is not *identical* with the value FALSE.

Comment: @JamesBowery To clarify, when I say "It's not" at the beginning of my previous comment, I mean what I'm saying is not contradicted by the text you linked to. What the book says *is* correct.

Comment: "But the symbol ⊥ is not identical with the value FALSE." So the fact that a symbol is invariably interpreted as the same value does not satisfy the requirements of an "identity" in some sense.  OK.  This gets into the definition of "identity" which is a topic of another discussion.

Comment: Getting back to "sets", when you say "As you know, we interpret n-place predicates as subsets of the n-ary Cartesian power of the domain of discourse." and then say "we interpret a 0-place predicate as {<>} when we want to say it's true in an interpretation, and {} when we want to say it's false in that interpretation."  The "we" here seems to be doing two levels of interpretation: First, the class of relationships is interpreted as a "set" of "tuples", and then interpret {<>} vs {} as logical values.  Is such a two-level interpretation afforded by model theory?

Comment: @JamesBowery It's arbitrary and entirely optional to view truth values that way. There isn't a two-level interpretation, formally. It's just that we keep in our mind that {<>} means true, and {} means false when specifying an interpretation. It's like in set theory, how we can [interpret the empty set, {}, as the number 0, the set {{}} as the number 1, and so on.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers). The downside is strange properties like 1 ∈ 2 and FALSE ⊂ TRUE. The upside is it's arguably more "elegant" that we avoid 0-place predicates as special cases.

Comment: D'oh! I wrote: "It's like in set theory, how we can interpret the empty set, {}, as the number 0, the set {{}} as the number 1, and so on." Really bad choice of words on my part, given the subject matter of our discussion. I should say we ***define*** some sets to be certain numbers, not ***interpret***, since this has nothing to do with ***interpretations*** in the sense that we've been discussing.

Comment: OK.  Please add to your answer the fact that a standard language for FOL may provide no arity-0 and, instead, only constants.  I'll then accept your answer.  (Although I remain skeptical of set theoretic language, given Quine's, I believe valid, argument in chapter 5 "The Scope of Logic" of his "Philosophy of Logic", that while identity belongs to FOL itself, set theory (ie the ∈ predicate) must be defined with additional axioms in FOL.)

Comment: @JamesBowery But I agree 100% with the view you just attributed to Quine. I wonder if [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121128/when-does-the-set-enter-set-theory) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334678/does-mathematics-become-circular-at-the-bottom-what-is-at-the-bottom-of-mathema) on Math SE might be relevant? You can see set theory as a theory of logic, where ∈ is a non-logical predicate and additional axioms specify its use. Or, you can see FOL as an object of study in math and bring set theoretic tools to bear on it (mathematical logic).

Answer (score 0):

The OP notes that [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Non-logical_symbols) of the non-logical symbols of first-order logic include 0-arity predicates and functions. The 0-arity predicates are used for *propositional variables* while the 0-arity functions are used for *constants*.

It is worth nothing Wikipedia's view of what non-logical symbols are:

> The non-logical symbols represent predicates (relations), functions and constants on the domain of discourse.

The constants would represent individuals from the domain of discourse, so having constants as non-logical symbols makes sense.  However, it is hard to see how propositional variables relate to the the domain of discourse.  They would more likely be logical symbols rather than non-logical symbols.

Not all presentations of the language of first-order logic use 0-arity predicates and functions.  The definition of a first-order language at the [Open Logic Project](https://openlogicproject.org/) does not use them. The set of non-logical symbols contain the following: (page 145-6)

> a) A denumerable set of n-place predicate symbols for each n > 0
>
> b) A denumerable set of constant symbols
>
> c) A denumerable set of n-place function symbols for each n > 0

The constant symbols are specified separately and there are no 0-arity predicates. They also mention that first-order languages only "sometimes" have function symbols.

The OP writes,

> Moreover, Quine goes so far as to render superfluous even the necessity of named constants by appropriately quantifying 1-arity predicates standing in for such names, such as the object denoted by 'a' with the 1-arity predicate 'A':

The constants in this list may be "convenient redundancy".

The question in the title involves more than redundancy. It may be that 0-arity predicates or propositional variables do not belong in the non-logical symbols list.

---

Open Logic Project https://openlogicproject.org/ Retrieved on June 6, 2019 at http://builds.openlogicproject.org/open-logic-complete.pdf

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, May 23). First-order logic. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 19:34, June 6, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=First-order_logic&oldid=898492463